# keyboard.is_pressed() not permitted in mac os Catalina

Tags: python, macos, keyboard, macos-catalina

I'm using mac os Catalina and I need to use

```
keyboard.is_pressed('a')
```

in my code. it raises this error:

> OSError: Error 13 - Must be run as administrator

I also use `sudo`  :

```
sudo python main.py
```

it raises this error:

> 2019-12-30 21:52:05.719 Python[6717:186981] ApplePersistenceIgnoreState: Existing state will not be touched. New state will be written to (null)
>
> Segmentation fault: 11

to be noted that I need to check if `a` is pressed or not. if no key pressed the progress should be continued. so getting input cannot solve this because the flow waits till that key be pressed.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just give your terminal an accessibility access.

I'm running MacOs Catalina, and this worked for me.

Go to `settings -> Security and Privacy -> Privacy Tab -> Accessibility`, and finally check your terminal